# Calling function from another contract

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to call another contract, and return the data - however it's unable to return the correct data (just a string set on the other contract)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
  address public constant OTHER_CONTRACT = 0x8016619281F888d011c84d2E2a5348d9417c775B;

  event Response(bool success, bytes data);

    function testCall() public returns (bytes memory) {
        (bool success,  bytes memory data) = OTHER_CONTRACT.call{gas: 50000}(abi.encodeWithSignature("greet()"));

        emit Response(success, data);

        return data;
    }
}
```

I'm testing this on Rinkeby, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something incorrectly here.

This is the contract I'm calling

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is easier to declare an interface and use it like below.

```
//Interface name is not important, however functions in it are important
interface GreeterInterface{
  function greet() external view returns (string memory);
  function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) external;
}

contract MyContract {
  address public constant OTHER_CONTRACT = 0x8016619281F888d011c84d2E2a5348d9417c775B;
  GreeterInterface GreeterContract = GreeterInterface(OTHER_CONTRACT);
  
  function testCall() public returns (string memory) {
    //This is example and not related to your contract
    string memory greet = GreeterContract.greet();
    return greet;
  }
}
```

Comment: Say I want to call the `ownerOf` function for another contract that inherits for ERC721 - would I just create an interface like ERC721Interface and have `ownerOf` defined in that interface?

Comment: Yes! But interface has a little difference with functions. First, you can't call a `private` or `internal` function, they just can be call within the contract they are deployed to. Second, you do not use words `override` and `virtual` in the interface (It is already `virtual`). Third, `public` and `internal` functions will be changed into `external`.