# How do I get the respective token address from a wallet address using solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.9.0;

contract HelloBlockchain {
    struct token {
        address token;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    token[] res;

    function getBalances(address walletAddress, address[] memory tokenAddress) public returns(token[] memory){
        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenAddress.length; i++) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(tokenAddress[i]).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", walletAddress));
            uint256 amount = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
            res.push(token(tokenAddress[i], amount));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The function parameters are a wallet address and an array of token addresses and the function would loop through the token addresses to find the wallet balance of this particular token. However, when I deploy and run the function, I keep running into false Transaction mined but execution error which I am unsure what it means and how to proceed

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

You can only call functions like this if they're childs of your contract or at least imported so yes, this line is invalid

`uint256 amt = tokenAddress[i].getBalances(walletAddress);`

but i think you're in the right path; you can call another contract using this:

```
//externalContractAddress
address contractFoo = 0x12000notFakeAddress00012739
//parameters like tokenId, etc.
parameters = bar 
(bool,data) = address(contractFoo).call("functionSignature",parameters)
```

Ie. I have an operator contract with a function that calls another contract to burn an NFT token like this:

```
function burn (address foo, uint256 id) external {
address contractFoo = 0x12000notFakeAddress00012739
    (bool burned,) = address(contractFoo).call(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("burn(address,uint256,uint256)", foo, id, 1)
    );
    require(burned, "Burn Failed");
}
```

Just replace the burn function singature (`"burn(address,uint256,uint256)"`) with the one to get balances from the other contract

_______New Edit

I did some refactor to your code; however I must apology because I also found another answer that is actually better than my own response [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109530/calling-function-from-another-contract), the reason is that call function can potentially trigger a blockchain storage change therefore the EVM will not allow you to use it as a view function, therefore calling this function will trigger a transaction that cost gas, you can infer this by reading the docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.9.0;

contract HelloBlockchain {
    struct token {
        address token;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    function getBalances(address walletAddress, address[] memory tokenAddress) public returns(token[] memory){
        //cant push or pull if the array is not in storage so i make a fixed size array with 
        //the max possible lenght
        token[] memory res = new token[](tokenAddress.length); 

        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenAddress.length; i++) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(tokenAddress[i]).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", walletAddress));
        if (success) {
            uint256 amount = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
            res[i]= token(tokenAddress[i], amount);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

For more detailed info look at the solidity docs on members of address, in there it explains more what is this [address.call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109530/calling-function-from-another-contract)

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you for your help. I edited to use address.call as suggested by you. However, I am currently facing false transaction mined but execution failed error which I am unsure of what it means and how to proceed from here. Hope you would be able to enlighten me. I have edited the code above and screenshotted the error message.

Comment: I assume that you get "False transaction mined bu exection failed error" because you're trying to use array.push, but that is not available on memory but only storage; I will add another answer to detail this

Answer (score 1):

**If the goal is to make your own token**

You must have the function getBalances declared somewhere. Often, we integrate an inheritance to an ERC, in this case ERC20.
And so, all balanced are saved in a private mapping.

**If the goal is to reach specific tokens**.

As mentioned by Carlos, you must call the other contract with its address.
But for security issue, and if the called smart contract are not trustable, I will recommend to avoid to use Call.
Instead use interface, and/or check what interface they use and what standard they respect.

If you need/want to use Call then you must consider the returned parameters:(bool success, bytes memory data), where data is a package of bytes where you will get, but not only, the returned value from the called function.And in this case better to use Assembler.

**If the goal is to get all tokens possible belonging to a wallet**

Then, there is no possibility because a wallet doesn't save any information.  Balances are saved in a contract on a key value (mapping if they respect some ERC): addressWallet -> amount.

Comment: This is correct.. I typed my example assuming that the function signature is the same in all the contracts and that the contracts themselves are to be trusted